# PHP: AJAX request to XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax, checkbox

I need help in identifying how I should set up this non public website.
Basically there are around 2000 images referenced in a database.
Each user will be able to check or uncheck each image with the use of a checkbox.
Some users might have different images checked or unchecked.

I want the checkbox to process an AJAX request to a user specific XML (PHP generated from the db) which contains a boolean variable for each image entry.

The PHP then references the XML and highlights checkedboxes and disables the uncheckedboxes.
Again each user will have different references for each image.

Im not sure if the above is the correct method to use.

I want the page to dynamically load the first 20 images and if the checkbox is changed, instantly updated and refreshed without a page reload. Then I'll paginate to the next 20.

If I'm on the right track I'll attempt a demo and post an update.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Reading up on JSON. I've never used AJAX or JSON before so might be a while before I have anything to show in terms of a demo. If anyone has any links regarding what I'm trying to achieve, that would be greatful.

Comment: As @Will said, it would be better to use json, but if you really want to use xml, you can do something like this: [xml to json](http://lostechies.com/seanbiefeld/2011/10/21/simple-xml-to-json-with-php/)

Comment: Its not the JSON or XML I'm worried about. I just need to know if I'm approaching this in the right way. I don't want to start working on it and then realise it wont work or its too slow. JSON is definately the better tool.

Comment: What functionality is the site going to have? What are the checkboxes actually for? Is it just a gallery or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to do it.  You'll need to brush up on your javascript as well to track the on change event. If you're bring in the images with ajax to begin with I would create an object for each and attach the event to element.  Then on click you could post the image_id or what have you to the server.  Alternatively you could use an attribute on the checkbox/image like `data-imageid="1"`

JSON or XML, both will work, it just depends how you want to design it. Though from my experience I would use JSON instead.

The JSON array you would return might look something like `{1:true,2:false,3:true}` etc, so foreach key value pair you would either check it be it true or not on false.

Consider editing your tags for javascript or jquery to see if you get some better answers. Or I could elaborate further if I'm on the right track.